# Copying raw mysql files to Windows 7 MySQL 5.6 obtained via mysqlhotcopy from Linux MySQL 5.1

Tags: linux, windows, mysql

Assuming I only have access to the raw files (`.myd`, `.myi`, `.frm`), would I simply copy+paste mysql db files obtained from `/var/lib/mysql/mydb` to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\data\mydb` or is it `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydb`? I was using mysql-5.1.43 on Linux and now mysql 5.6 on Windows 7. I don't have access to the Linux anymore.

I have tried the top 2 Windows locations with no success. I cannot even tell where data is actually being kept when I create a new schema in Workbench; neither of the two locations have the actual data files for the new dummy schema I create, even after I post some data to the tables.

I don't seem to get any direct answer to my question on similar questions asked on this site.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyISAM data can indeed simply be copied from one MySQL instance to the next. If you don't know where to put the data, your running MySQL instance can tell you:

```
mysql> select @@datadir\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@datadir: /srv/mysql/
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes indeed I've found the path to the data through the command above. However, and I hope this will now nail it, the file extensions are different somewhat - i.e. instead of `.opt, .myd, .myi, .frm` I now see `.opt, .ibd, .frm`. How do I integrate the two? Do I simply (with MySQL being off) erase the new format files and copy the old data-laden format?

Comment: Actually, I did as above (replaced the new with the old) and it's now fully functional. Thanks a lot!